# Tensorboard not showing loss

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, automl

I am trying to train autokeras with tensorboard.
In tensorboard, every method shows train loss, etc..
But, the method which include adam_weighted_decay not show every loss.
The yellow line in picture.

Also, I add my code that part of tensorboard.

```
logdir = './logs/' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logdir)

predict_from = 1
predict_until = 10
lookback = 5
clf = ak.TimeseriesForecaster(
    lookback  = lookback,
    predict_from = predict_from,
    predict_until= predict_until,
    max_trials = 30,
    #tuner = 'random',
    objective = 'val_loss',
)

clf.fit(
    x = data_x,
    y = data_y,
    validation_data = (data_x_val, data_y_val),
    batch_size = 32,
    epochs = 10,
    callbacks = [tensorboard_callback],
)
```

How can I solve this problem?

[image]